# Separate data into 3 fields

Tags: php, mysql

In my form: I have 8 checkboxes that will save to MySQL as a string/varchar (not an int).

Ex:

- Checkbox 1 = Apple
- Checkbox 2 = Orange
- Checkbox 3 = Mango
- Checkbox 4 = Grape
- Checkbox 5 = Watermelon
- Checkbox 6 = Melon
- Checkbox 7 = Pineapple
- Checkbox 8 = Cherry

Now, I want to output this to 3 different fields with limited number of characters per field.

- Field 1 = Has a limit of 25 Characters
- Field 2 = Has a limit of 30 Characters
- Field 3 = Has an unlimited Characters

If all checkboxes are check and save into MySQL, the output will be:

- FIELD 1: `Apple, Orange, Mango` (this field can only hold 25 characters, so I have to put the next variable data into FIELD 2).
- FIELD 2: `Grape, Watermelon` (this field can only hold 25 characters, so I have to put the next variable data into FIELD 3).
- FIELD 3: `Melon, Pineapple, and Cherry`

I did some research on STRLEN, EXPLODE, etc. and somehow I can't put this together in PHP.
How could I do it?

Comment: What did you put together so far? Maybe someone can simply point out a bug or two that's causing it to fail.

Comment: Why would you design the fields like that?  It seems sure to cause more grief than happiness.  Unless it is a homework question; it has all the pointlessness characteristics of a task devised by a sadistic teacher (not to mention incomplete specification).  All else apart, is that `'and'` required between the last two entries (assuming there are at least two)?  And are commas required at the ends of the first two fields if the data fits?  Is a space required to separate values, or will that be added when the three fields are later concatenated?

Comment: i was just using an example based on fruits, but these 3 fields are from a PDF form that are seperated in 3 different areas that has 3 text field. But will populated as a string from MySQL that answered from the checkbox via php. I just need break 1 string of data into 3 variable that will be output into 3 different field in my PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps wordwrap will do the trick? One way of doing it is (not tested):

```
$string_list = explode("\n", wordwrap($string, 25));
$field1 = array_shift($string_list);
$string = implode(" ",$string_list);

$string_list = explode("\n", wordwrap($string, 30));
$field2 = array_shift($string_list);

$field3 = implode("\n", $string_list);
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't so far. Here's my example code: $string = "Apple, Orange, Mango, Grape, Watermelon, Melon, Pineapple, Cherry;
$field1 = wordwrap($string, 25);$field2 = wordwrap($field1, 25);$field3 = wordwrap($field2, 100); This is what I tried so far, but all 3 fields show the same content as 1 long string. Sorry if they are all in 1 paragraph, for some reason I cannot add a break line in this mini comment box

Comment: Thank you, Brent Baisley! You're a life saver.